# Ubuntu drains battery very fast on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dell, power-management, battery

I have Dell XPS L502X

I have installed SSD of kingstone  120 gb After that i have i have installed ubutu 16.04 and my battery drain very fast at 100% charging work 1 hour and 13 minutes while in window it stay around 4 hours

then i have installed `powertop` from [http://linuxpitstop.com/install-powertop-on-ubuntu/][1]

```
Bad           VM writeback timeout                                                                                   
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host0
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host1
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host2
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host3
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host4
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host5
Bad           Enable Audio codec power management
Bad           NMI watchdog should be turned off
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-2 (i915 gmbus panel)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-6 (DPDDC-C)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-1 (i915 gmbus vga)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-4 (i915 gmbus dpb)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-5 (i915 gmbus dpd)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-0 (i915 gmbus ssc)
Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-3 (i915 gmbus dpc)
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
Bad           Wake-on-lan status for device enp6s0
```

what i have to do??

Comment: possible duplcate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/387388/ubuntu-drains-battery-very-fast-compared-to-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

1. Install `tlp` (with command`sudo apt-get install tlp`), then under `Tunables` tab at `powertop` most parameters should switch to "Good" once the laptop is unplugged (use r to refresh powertop).
2. Open `Software & Updates` and at the `Additional Drivers` tab select the proprietary gpu driver if it is available. Also `intel-microcode` may be a good option if it is also available.